# how to open a child window?

Tags: python, tkinter

please help to fix the script.

```
import tkinter

def winMake(parent):
    win = tkinter.Frame(parent)
    win.config(relief = 'sunken', width = 340, height = 170, bg = 'red')
    win.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')

    msg = tkinter.Button(win, text='press me', command = addFormOpen)
    msg.pack()

def addFormOpen():
    addForm = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
    Label(addForm, text = 'ertert').pack()
    print('fff')

root = tkinter.Tk()
winMake(root)
root.mainloop()
```

after clicking on the button "press me" should open a child window. but the console displays an error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Python33\projects\DVD_LIS\p3_dvd_list_shelve_3d_class_edit_menubar\q.py", line 13, in addFormOpen
    Label(addForm, text = 'ertert').pack() 
NameError: global name 'Label' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You imported the name `tkinter` which *contains* the class `Label`.  Meaning, in order to access it, you need to put `tkinter.` before it (just like you did for `Frame`, `Button`, etc.):

```
tkinter.Label(addForm, text = 'ertert').pack()
```

Otherwise, Python will not know where `Label` is defined.